# Mutable list in data class being initialized as ImmutableCollections$ListN

Tags: kotlin, collections, immutability

Consider following Kotlin code:

```kotlin
data class CachedUserData(var contracts: MutableList<String>) {
    var localDateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
}
```

When I'm trying to get via auto-generated getter contracts list and modify it from outside, I'm getting exception thrown `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null`. Investigation shows, that in this class the `contracts` field is being initialized to type `ImmutableCollections$ListN`.

I'm able to bypass this by adding following data modification function:

```
    fun addContract(item: String) {
        val newList = mutableListOf(*contracts.toTypedArray());
        newList.add(item);
        contracts = newList;
    }
```

then, this type directly after this class construction is `ImmutableCollections$ListN`, but after it's modification via this function call is changed to `ArrayList` and stays that way.

The instance of this particular class is created as a result of network resource fetch (plain Java `List`), that is afterwards being passed by stream to some filtering, and afterwards is being collected by `.toList()` Java collector.

My questions would be:

- Why initial type is set to ImmutableCollection, even I'm trying to strongly persuade Kotlin that  I'd love to have this list to be modifiable?
- Is there a way to make it initially make them modifiable and use simple construct of `.getContracts().add(value);`?
- Is there a place, where such behavior is described in details? I.e. some implicit collections conversions to some immutable shadowing types?

Edit:
This class is instantiated in some Java part of project, and it's supplied with `List<String>` type as input parameter:

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is initialising `CachedUserData`? Only they know why they created an immutable list. Please show where and how you create instances of `CachedUserData`.

Comment: It's instantiated from Java part of the code with plain `List` collection type, that by definition is mutable

Comment: "that by definition is mutable" No it is not. From the information you found, you are creating a list on the Java side using `List.of(...)`? That creates an immutable list.

Comment: Thank you for expertise @Sweeper. The list that is being supplied is sourced, in the very end, as a result of stream being collected into the list via `.toList()` collector.

Comment: I see. That is very important information that should be edited into the question. You need to change the Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have an extra type to distinguish mutable lists from immutable lists. All lists, mutable or immutable are represented by the `java.util.List` type. In Kotlin, *both* `List` and `MutableList` are mapped to `java.util.List` interface in Java. See the mapping table [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

Even if you say your class' constructor should take a `MutableList` in Kotlin, the constructor takes a `java.util.List` as far as Java is concerned. Therefore, code in Java can pass both mutable and immutable lists to it.

You said that the Java code is passing the result of a [`Stream.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) call to the constructor, and that is the problem - `toList` is designed to return an immutable list:

> The returned `List` is unmodifiable; calls to any mutator method will always cause `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown.

You should instead use `Collectors.toCollection` to control the type of the list that is returned, and pass in a supplier of a *mutable* list type.

```
// e.g. replace .toList() with
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

Alternatively, instead of making a mutable copy of the list in `addContract`, you can do this in an `init` block instead:

```
data class CachedUserData(var contracts: MutableList<String>) {
    init {
        contracts = ArrayList(contracts)
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I highly appreciate your effort in helping me :)